# Upgrading vb6 application to visual studio 2008 with Mysql ODBC driver

Tags: mysql, vb.net, visual-studio-2008, vb6, odbc

I am very "lucky" to get to work with a VB application that was originally written in vb6 with an old version of Mysql ODBC connector.

The problem is i can't open the project in my copy of VS2008 because i don't have the needed file MyVbQl.DLL and i can't find it anywhere on the internet and also Mysql ODBC connector versions 3 and 5 don't suppy that dll file.

Does somebody know how to open that dammed thing? Is there a way how to force it to ignore that error or import the newer version of mysql odbc?

Here is the [screenshot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EX2te.jpg).

Comment: You didn't look very hard, google has thousands of hits.

Comment: but i could not find that myvbql.dll file anywhere and its not part of mysql odbc connector

Comment: Browse to google and type "myvbql.dll" in the search box.  Download only to an isolated machine.

Answer (score 0):

To fix `myvbql.dll` error and associated error messages, you have to analyse the nature and causes how the problems origins. You can replace the missing `myvbql.dll` file from another operating system and re-start the program or reboot your computer. In most cases, you still need to register the file to Windows Registry, which stores all the information of Windows configurations, settings and third party program information. Re-installing the program and rebooting your computer may resolve the error and fix the associated `Windows Registry` issues. However, you could further damage your computer in case you're not familiar with `Windows Registry` and failed to edit the associated Registry entries correctly.

Comment: The problem was that the original programmer did a realy crappy job at maintaining his projects, i moved on from that project and rewrote the whole thing because it was easier.

And i managed to run the project via a virtual machine of the original OS and dev environment. It was fun :)